# Glide not loading image from memory at the first time when rotating (orientation change), and after that it is loading from memory

Tags: android, image-loading, android-glide

Glide not loading image from memory at the first time when rotating (orientation change), and after that it is loading from memory.

I have tried to increase the memory size, the bitmap pool size, all kinds of caching strategies... nothing seemed to work...

I have attached a video.

https://youtu.be/szDnAGxrJLU

Thanks!

Comment: Here's the related Glide issue: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/598

Answer (score 5):

`.dontAnimate()` adding this to Glide solved my problem

```
Glide.with(view.getContext())
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(placeholder_image_crop))
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(view)
```

You may face this issue because of

`CircleImageView/CircularImageView/RoundedImageView` are known to have issues with `TransitionDrawable` **(.crossFade() with .thumbnail() or .placeholder())** and animated `GIFs`, use a `BitmapTransformation` **(.circleCrop() will be available in v4)** or `.dontAnimate()` to fix the issue.

for more queries refer following links it may help you.
[link 1](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [link 2](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1026#issuecomment-191709837)

Comment: If you use `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView` you'll need to add `dontAnimate()` as shown on this answer

Comment: This solved my issue as well. Image wouldn't load the first time the function is called once the fragment is created. I would destroy and recreate the fragment and then it would load. Adding dont animate() fixed it for me

Answer (score 3):

Your `ImageView`s don't have the exact same size in portrait and in landscape and you are probably using `fitCenter()` or `centerCrop()` to resize the image to the `ImageView` size. When you change orientation, Glide loads the full-sized image from cache but it has to resize it on a background thread first before display, that's why you see a delay after the first orientation change. After resized images for both portrait and landscape are in the memory cache, there is no more delay.

Answer (score 2):

Just to emphasize what is written above and add a solution.

It is possible to change the disk caching strategy to cache the source image but not the memory caching strategy, in that case it will not hit unless it is the same size.

What i did was use .override(width,height) in order to override this strategy and keep the source image in the memory cache.

```
        Glide.with(context)
             .load(imgUrl)
             .crossFade()
             .override(imageWidth,imageHeight)
             .into(imgView);
```

Answer (score 0):

To load image from cache you can pass `DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE` to load images from cache.

You can use glide like below and keep don't animate method as it helps to load images in adapter without updating full list. For more check [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/757)

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(row_object.getImage())
    .dontAnimate() // will load image
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
        R.mipmap.ic_user_placeholder_50dp))
    .into(holder.rowIvPostUserIcon);
```

Comment: `.dontAnimate()` adding this to `Glide` solved my problem. thanks

Comment: Same for me @Sagar. The image didn't load the first time (had to open another screen and go back to see it). Adding `.dontAnimate()` fixed the issue. I've used Glide since 2015 but never had to do this before. Really weird :/

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo the problem is with circular image view please check the the answer I have posted below.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar the project I'm working on does indeed use `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView`

Answer (score 0):

This code help me:

```
Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.vector_placeholder_vendor_image_crop))
                .dontAnimate()
                .into(view);

//need add .dontAnimate()
```

For more information:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1026#issuecomment-191709837

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

First Time glide is unable to load image on custom view like circular Imageview.you Can use error to load image on first time.

The following snippet should help you:

```
 Glide.with(context)
         .load(imgUrl)
         .crossFade()
         .override(imageWidth,imageHeight).error(R.drawable.yourdrawable)
         .into(imgView);
```